# Factorizing large numbers

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, factorization

I am trying to factorize large prime numbers with the code bellow. The code works properly for values like 1927 and 69527 (results), but gives no result for larger values like 655051. The code goes as follows:

```
myfunction[n_, B_] :=Module[{a, g, i},
    a=2;
    i=2;
    g=1;
    While[i<B && g==1,
        a=PowerMod[a,i,n];
        g=GCD[a-1,n];
        If[g>1&&g<n,Return[g]];
        i=i+1];
]
```

This works  `myfunction[69527,11]`
But this doesn't  `myfunction[655051,100]` Any idea what might be the problem?

Comment: Maybe a trivial question, but why factorize prime numbers?

Comment: Is `pollard` the same as `myfunction`?

Comment: Consider that `myfunction[69527, 9]` fails and `myfunction[864109, 55]` succeeds.

Comment: B must be big enough that the Pollard algorithm can run to its end. IIs it really necessary to have this constrain on `i` ?

Comment: @A.G. it's used for cracking RSA encryption

Comment: @MichaelE2 Yes exactly! You are on point I had to increase the boundary, however, that doesn't work for other primes like 655051. I wrote the same algorithm in C++ and works fine, with a result of 991, but I can't figure out why is not working in mathematica. Since I am new to this, is there something wrong with the code?

Comment: @DanielHuber It doesn;t work for all cases by increasing the boundary, so I think I am missing something. I use as counter.

Comment: Perhaps instead of `PowerMod`, you could use the more traditional `a = Mod[a^2 + 1, n]`.

Comment: @JohnCarter So maybe you mean "factorize non-prime numbers" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the Pollard algorithm may fail because it is based on a pseudo random sequence. In this case you may start with a different value from 2. See e.g.: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard%27s_rho_algorithm

Here is a working example where you may specify the start value:

```
pollard[n_, start_ : 2] := Module[{x, y, d = 1, g, gg},
  x = y = start;
  g[x_] = Mod[x^2 + 1, n];
  gg[x_] = g[g[x]];
  While[d == 1,
   x = g[x];
   y = gg[x];
   d = GCD[x - y, n]
   ];
  If[d == n, "Not found", d]
  ]
```

With this: "pollard[655051]" does not work or it takes too long, but the following will:

```
pollard[655051, 3]
(* 661 *)
```

Further, note, faster than Pollard is the quadratic sieve algorithm.